# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de una URL e insertarlo en un enlace de WhatsApp?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy intentando generar un enlace de WhatsApp para consultas, el problema que tengo es que no hallo el modo de modificar el `href` y que tome el valor de la url del sitio.

Se me ocurrió utilizar `${window.location.href}`, pero no corre ni correrá...

```html
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=54NÚMERO&amp;text=Hola, tengo una consulta. Enviado desde: ${window.location.href}">Consulta</a>
```

El resultado que deseo obtener en el mensaje es:

> Hola, tengo una consulta. Enviado desde: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/

*¿Cómo pudiese obtener el valor de la url e insertarlo en enlace WhatsApp?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente:

**Antes Carga la librería jquery**

```
<a id="whatsappbtn">Consulta</a>
```

```js
// capturas el objeto "a" en la variable link
$link = document.querySelector("#whatsappbtn"); 
// defines el campo href deseado en $url
$url = "https://wa.me/12345678/?text=Hola, tengo una consulta. Enviado desde: " + window.location.href; 
// agregas el atributo almacenado en $url al href de a, representado por $link
$link.setAttribute('href', $url);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="whatsappbtn">Consulta</a>
```

Comment: ¿Para qué se necesita _jQuery_? Además, las respuestas con solo código, sin explicación, generalmente no son bien recibidas.

Comment: @Triby, puede ofrecer otra solución y responder a la pregunta si le parece conveniente. Ya los moderadores de SO sabrán si vale la pena o no la respuesta.

Comment: No lo tomes a mal, tu respuesta es buena, pero puedes mejorarla agregando una explicación del código para que haya un aprendizaje y no solo la solución del problema.

Comment: Ok @Triby, te entiendo, no soy experto en código; pero me lio mucho a veces buscando respuestas o haciendo preguntas que nadie contesta por parecer "faciles" para los más expertos, a veces veo y pues, temas con que me topé en el pasado y encontré respuesta y si sirven las comparto con quienes tiene esa misma duda. He agregado comentarios al código para más claridad.

Comment: ¡Mucho mejor ahora! Aunque suene raro, a veces aprendes más explicando que investigando y, de paso, ayudas a que otros aprendan.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda @Elboy, solo tengo la misma duda que Tribi ¿por qué o para qué utilizar la librería de Jquery? Hice la prueba sin la librería y funciona, tanto en Codepen y otros. ¡Gracias nuevamente!

Comment: @Triby buena observación el considerar lo del aprendizaje explicativo, de esa forma crecemos. Buena comunidad.

Comment: @Carola, supongo que no era necesaria, pero no se porqué al incrustar el código minetras creaba la entrada me daba error. Igual me alegra que te haya servido.

Comment: @Elboy me topé con otro problema: Habilitaré dos links para las consultas WhatsApp, pero con diferentes números, es decir dos teléfonos ¿cómo podría habilitar dos enlaces con una diferente cadena de mensaje y número de teléfono? ¿Te parece si modifico la pregunta agregando tu aporte? Espero no abusar de tu tiempo, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Se me ocurren 2 opciones, alguna condicional o simplemente repitiendo el código pero con otro ID para el segundo botón y otras variables para $link y $url

Comment: También pensé en agregar otra id, pero eso cargaría el código. En ese sentido lo cambié a class y ahí me topé con el problema, ya que cambia la url de ambas class con la misma dirección. Veo conveniente quedarme con class y tengo esta remota idea: `https://wa.me/ + número + mensaje + window.location.href` y que el número y mensaje se extraiga desde el html y no necesariamente desde Jquery. ¿Crees que pueda ser posible, @Elboy?

Comment: Con class no te funciona porque estás seleccionando 2 objetos al mismo tiempo, usa ids "whatsappbtn" y "whatsappbtn2", y para el código, "$link", "$link2" y asi con el resto, un código independiente para cada botón. Puedes dejar la clase solamente para dar estilo a ambos botones y no tener que repetir css.

Comment: Todo bien, @Elboy, lo haré de ese modo. Te agradezco mucho el aporte.